# Django Feed.item_link: URL depends on both the item and the get_object parameters

Tags: django

I have an application with entries and containers. There is a ManyToMany relationship between them:

- A container contains 0 or more entries
- An entry is in 0 or more containers

I use the following schema for URIs:

- prefix/container
- prefix/container/entry

This means that several URLs can lead to the same entry. Each URL defines a different context.

I'm trying to create a RSS/Atom Feed for each container. My issue is how to implement the `Feed.item_link` method to returns
the right URL. I need to invoke `urlresolvers.reverse` with two arguments: the container identifier and the entry identifier. 
Unfortunately item_link receives only the entry as parameter. Only `Feed.get_object` method knows about the container. What is the cleanest solution to solve this issue ?

Sample code follows:

#### Models

```
    class Entry(models.Model):
        pass

    class Container(models.Model):
        entries = models.ManyToManyField("Entries",
                related_name='containers',
                null=True,
                blank=True
        )
```

#### URLs

```
    url(r'^prefix/(?P<container_slug>[-\w]+)/rss$', feeds.LatestEntries()),
```

#### Feed

```
    class LatestEntries(Feed):
        title = "foo"
        description = "bar"

        def get_object(self, request, container_slug):
            return get_object_or_404(models.Container, slug=container_slug)

        def item_link(self, entry):
            # TODO: How to pass container_slug to reverse() ?
            return urlresolvers.reverse('up.views.portfolio_image', kwargs={
                    'container_slug': 'FIXME',
                    'entry_slug': entry.slug,
                })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With syndication the situation is complicated by the fact that a single instance of `Feed` is used to handle all requests, therefore you can't reliably store the value as an attribute of the `Feed` instance, instead, you have to somehow use the objects you create to pass the value forward. I can only think of one way forward in this case, short of reimplementing the whole `Feed` class yourself.

You'll need to attach the argument to the object returned by `get_object`, for example like this (although this step seems redundant in this case as your `Container` instances will contain this as a regular model field already):

```
def get_object(self, request, container_slug):
    object = get_object_or_404(models.Container, slug=container_slug)
    object.container_slug = container_slug
    return object
```

Then, in `items`, you'll have to take this value from the container instance and attach it to each item returned, for example:

```
def items(self, container):
    result = list(Entry.objects.filter(field__exact=container.something)[:10])
    for entry in result:
        entry.container_slug = container.container_slug
    return result
```

You can avoid enumerating the queryset in this step by using a closure and a generator for the list of entries if you feel like it, although it shouldn't matter in this case if you're only returning a handful of entries.

Then, finally, you can implement `item_link` like this:

```
def item_link(self, entry):
    return urlresolvers.reverse('up.views.portfolio_image', kwargs={
            'container_slug': entry.container_slug,
            'entry_slug': entry.slug,
        })
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. It clarifies that we have to write the glue code. I was not sure if I overlooked something in the API.

Comment: Yeah, this is one use case the API wasn't really designed to cope with that well. Fortunately though, you don't need to add that much glue code, only modify a couple of methods.